# I can add comments on an old election

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, moderator-tools, election

I was looking at an old election page, and I noticed that I am able to add comments, as well as the other standard moderator actions for comments (deleting, editing, etc.):

[image]

I clicked "add a comment", fully expecting it to not work, and yet when I reloaded the page (while logged out), I saw my comment there. I haven't tested editing or deleting other comments, since that seems more destructive.

I suspect this only works on sites I moderate, since when I checked another site, it does not work. For reference, here is what it's supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's a bug? Moderator can add comments on deleted posts as far as I know, why elections posts are different? (Assuming they're considered as "deleted" behind the scenes once elections are over)

Answer (score 6):

They're just regular comments, so the election post is either locked or something very similar when the elections ends. As a Moderator♦, you are able to continue commenting on locked/deleted posts. As a regular user (on other sites), you don't have that access.

Comment: Should we intoduce the new type of user: the Regulator?

Comment: @älёxölüt For... what? Sorry, I lost you there.

Comment: @älёxölüt That role would be supplied by CMs, who have more powers than moderators (as Robert Cartaino can attest).